# What do I do after generating SSH keys?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I have 2 Linux machines: My NAS at home and a server off-site.

Call my NAS as "NAS" and the offset server "SRV".

I need to be able to copy files from SRV to NAS securely, without having to enter a password. SRV runs Ubuntu 14.04, so I can run `ssh-keygen`. NAS runs some other flavour of Linux (I can't figure out what. `cat /etc/*-release` and `lsb-release -a` both don't work). NAS has `ssh-keygen` but not `ssh-copy-id` and I don't want to install any additional software on NAS as others have had problems doing so.

Here is the confusion. I run `ssh-keygen` and 2 files are generated on the machine. I'm not exactly sure what the files are and which one I should be distributing. The other thing is, which machine do I actually run `ssh-keygen` on? Logic suggests if I want to log into NAS from SRV, I should run the command on SRV, but what reading I've done suggests it might actually be the other way around?

Here's what I've done so far:

I've logged into NAS with the user I wish to SSH as. I've run `ssh-keygen` and copied the id_rsa.pub file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on SRV. Then I tried to SSH from SRV to NAS but it asked for a password. Then I tried to SSH from SRV to NAS specifying the identity file using `ssh user@NAS -i ~/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub` but it still asked for a password.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. This seems to be something that *should* be a very simple process so I'm obviously doing something wrong or used the wrong SSH parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, you just have it backwards.

When you do an `ssh-keygen` you are generating a public and private keypair.  The private key should never leave the device it is created on, and the public key should be distributed to any server that you want to log into using keys.

So the `ssh-keygen` should be run on SRV and the `id_rsa.pub` file created should be copied to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the NAS in the home directory of the **user you are logging in as**.

If this file is newly created (or anyway) make sure that its permissions are restricted to the owner only:

```
 chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is actually what I've done. So perhaps the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: This is the opposite way around from what you described.  But if you have done it this way too, perhaps the NAS ssh configuration needs to be altered to accept ssh keys.  Can you edit you post and add the output from `ssh -vvvvv user@nas`

Comment: I believe my post is already the correct way around? Read the 2nd last paragraph. *I've logged into NAS with the user [...]*. The command is `ssh user@NAS -p [port] -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. The output is nothing special, it just asks for the user's password to log in.

Answer (score 0):

What I have read you did everything rigth . If it is not working try to clear 
`known_hosts` file then generate new ssh key and add it to `authorized_keys`. This should solve your problem.